# Configure remote debug using kotlin spring and docker

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea, docker-compose

Hi I have a problem to configure debug in my application, I use spring boot with kotlin using docker, follow my configuration files:

Dockerfile

```
FROM  gradle:6.4-jdk14

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -qq -y --no-install-recommends

ENV INSTALL_PATH /weblib

RUN mkdir -p $INSTALL_PATH

WORKDIR $INSTALL_PATH

COPY . .

RUN gradle clean && gradle bootJar
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  weblibdb:
    image: "postgres:12.3"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=weblib
      - POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  weblibapi:
    build: .
    command: bash start.sh
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
      - "5005:5005"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USERNAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - GRADLE_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005
    volumes:
      - .:/weblib
    depends_on:
      - weblibdb

volumes:
  postgres:
```

start.sh

```
gradle bootRun
```

my container works fine and the remote debug created in IDE connect with container but breakpoints not work, follow my configuration:

[image]

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably to late for you, but for every lost soul who ends here:

### **SHORT ANSWER**

Add to your `build.gradle`:

```
bootRun {
    jvmArgs '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005'
}
```

Execute `gradle bootRun` in your container (or `CMD ["gradle","bootRun"]` in your Dockerfile) and attach the jvm debugger

---

### **LONG ANSWER**

I had the same problem. I had a kotlin gradle project, which should run in a docker container, but i wanted to use IntelliJ Idea for writing and debuging on my host system.

I used Gradle 7.1, Java 11. The Container had the environment variable
`GRALDE_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005`
set.

I followed the instruction to setup a remote jvm debugger in IntelliJ[1].

`gradle run` waited for the attachment of the debugger. However, the code was executed, but the debugger did not stop at the breakpoints in the IDE.

The problem was, the debugger was attached to the JVM process of the gradle daemon, not the JVM process, which executed the actual code.
A few different sources recommend `gradle run --debug-jvm`, however this do not work with Java > 8[2].
The solution was, to add the JVM args in the `build gradle`.

For example, if you use `gradle run` to start your application, you need to add

```
run {
    jvmArgs '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=*:5005'
}
```

Then you could use `gradle run` to start your programm, attach the debugger and the execution will stop at the breakpoints.

[1]: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-a-java-application-using-a-dockerfile.html#create-remote-debug-config)
[2]: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/7496

Comment: This and next solution works, in this option need to modify build.gradle, at next answer needs to run jar out of gralde. This way works too for debug tests if this args is added on Test task, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I change my configurations and works, follow my changes:

remove the follow commands from Dockerfile:

```
RUN gradle clean && gradle bootJar
```

change my start.sh to:

```
gradle clean
gradle bootJar
java -jar -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005 build/libs/weblib.jar
```

I a docker-compose.yml I change `suspend=y` to `suspend=n` in enviroment `GRADLE_OPTS`, but it's optional.